# How to export a png file from a raster file? r.out.png has an error

Tags: raster, grass-gis, png

I used r.out.png to export a png file, but it produced this error:

```
(Sun Feb 27 00:26:32 2011)                                                      
r.out.png input=raster_bulacanElevation output=png_bulacanElevation.png         
rows = 382, cols = 819
ERROR: Not able to open file for [png_bulacanElevation.png]
(Sun Feb 27 00:26:33 2011) Command finished (0 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is reached if GRASS is unable to write to the current folder, try specifying a path that GRASS can write to in your `output` value.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to put quotation marks in the path that is why it failed to open the path. Is there a way to convert both the raster and vector map that is displayed in the GRASS GIS Map Display Window into a single PNG file? r.out.png only saves the raster file

Comment: Yes, use d.out.file for this if use you use the classical GRASS monitor. For the wxPython based interface, use the "Save display to graphics file" or "Print display" functionality. Consider also to read the manual...